# Dynamic sender from PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, sender

I'm using phpmailer in my app, and i want it to be used by multiple users, but without changing the smtp server. here's what i want to do.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Username = "mygmailtestaccount@gmail.com"; 
$mail->Password = "pwd0"; 

$mail->SetFrom("myoutlooktestaccount@hotmail.com","User name test");
$to = "receiveroutlooktestaccount@hotmail.co.jp";
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->Subject = "Testing PHPMailer Message";
$mail->AltBody = "Email viewer!  please do no spam me !!! \n";
$mail->WordWrap = 80;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
if (!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "im in error zone";
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

The problem is that i get the email with the sender as gmail "mygmailtestaccount@gmail.com", but i want my app to be only a "jump", to send emails from it regardless of my SMTP provider.

Comment: This is not going to end well. You're essentially doing what spammers are doing - using utterly unrelated SMTP servers to fake a From: address. Even if google allowed you to set an `@hotmail.com` "From:", the backtrace in the mail headers would show a Google origin, and wouldn't have hotmail DKIM.

Comment: I'm not going to spam, i'm going to make a business campaign website, to give the hand to users to create their own email, and send it with their email, not mine.

Comment: didn't say you were spamming, but it's essentially exactly the same as spamming. using "smtp.example.com" to forge emails as coming from some OTHER domain, e.g. hotmail.

Comment: So how can i make dynamic senders ? Using one single SMTP server and account ?

Comment: any way you want, I'm just saying that your emails are likely to get trashed as spam because your server is **NOT** going to be an official "source" of emails for the mails you're sending out.

Comment: but it's the **WAY** That i'm looking for, I'm sending to 100 000 emails at once, doesn't matter if some go to spam, i just want to know a way to send them with different sender (**FROM**), which will stand for each user who use my service.

Answer (score 0):

You need a lowercase s for setFrom:

```
     /**
     * Set the From and FromName properties.
     * @param string $address
     * @param string $name
     * @param bool $auto Whether to also set the Sender address, defaults to true
     * @throws phpmailerException
     * @return bool
     */
    public function setFrom($address, $name = '', $auto = true)
```

Taken from: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php